# python - Fill in missing dates with respect to a specific attribute in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My data looks like below:

```
id, date, target
1,2016-10-24,22
1,2016-10-25,31
1,2016-10-27,44
1,2016-10-28,12
2,2016-10-21,22
2,2016-10-22,31
2,2016-10-25,44
2,2016-10-27,12
```

I want to fill in missing dates among id. 
For example, the date range of id=1 is 2016-10-24 ~ 2016-10-28, and 2016-10-26 is missing. Moreover, the date range of id=2 is 2016-10-21 ~ 2016-10-27, and 2016-10-23, 2016-10-24 and 2016-10-26 are missing.
I want to fill in the missing dates and fill in the target value as 0.

Therefore, I want my data to be as below:

```
id, date, target
1,2016-10-24,22
1,2016-10-25,31
1,2016-10-26,0
1,2016-10-27,44
1,2016-10-28,12
2,2016-10-21,22
2,2016-10-22,31
2,2016-10-23,0
2,2016-10-24,0
2,2016-10-25,44
2,2016-10-26,0
2,2016-10-27,12
```

Can somebody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) - then is problem `fillna` - so need [`asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.asfreq.html) first:

```
#if necessary convert to datetime
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df = df.set_index('date')
df = df.groupby('id').resample('d')['target'].asfreq().fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index()
print (df)
    id       date  target
0    1 2016-10-24      22
1    1 2016-10-25      31
2    1 2016-10-26       0
3    1 2016-10-27      44
4    1 2016-10-28      12
5    2 2016-10-21      22
6    2 2016-10-22      31
7    2 2016-10-23       0
8    2 2016-10-24       0
9    2 2016-10-25      44
10   2 2016-10-26       0
11   2 2016-10-27      12
```