# When to use a custom index rather than ordinary columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In pandas you can replace the default integer-based index with an index made up of any number of columns using [`set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html).

What confuses me, though, is *when* you would want to do this. Regardless of whether the series is a column or part of the index, you can filter values in the series using [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for columns, or [xs()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) for rows. You can sort on the columns or index using either [`sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) or [`sort_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html).

The only real difference I've encountered is that indexes have issues when there are duplicate values, so it seems that using an index is more restrictive, if anything.

Why then, would I want to convert my columns into an index in Pandas?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion custom indexes are good for quickly selecting data.

They're also useful for aligning data for [mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43492703/2901002), for [aritmetic operations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654041/2901002) where the index is used for data alignment, for [joining](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43568269/2901002) data, and for getting minimal or [maximal rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44601293/2901002) per group.

[`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) is nice for [partial string indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing), for [resampling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41830357/2901002).

But you are right, a duplicate index is problematic, especially for [reindexing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39792933/2901002).

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html):

> - Identifies data (i.e. provides metadata) using known indicators, important for analysis, visualization, and interactive console display
> - Enables automatic and explicit data alignment
> - Allows intuitive getting and setting of subsets of the data set

Also you can check [Modern pandas - Indexes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html#modern-pandas), [direct link](http://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-3-indexes.html).

Comment: Good call, citing the index documentation. I'd never even noticed that paragraph

Comment: Thank you. I try add all ways what sometimes used, but I believe there is more situtations where seting index is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

As of 0.20.2, some methods, such as `.unstack()`, only work with indices.

Custom indices, especially indexing by time, can be particularly convenient. Besides resampling and aggregating over any time interval (the latter is done using `.groupby()` with `pd.TimeGrouper()`) which require a `DateTimeIndex`, you can call the `.plot()` method on a column, e.g. `df['column'].plot()` and immediately get a time series plot.

The most useful though, is alignment: for example, suppose you had some two sets of data that you want to add; they're labeled consistently, but sorted in a different order. If you set their labels to be the index of their dataframe, you can simply add the dataframes together and not worry about the ordering of the data.